# How to create series of date using open office

Tags: openoffice-calc

I am new to Open office how to create Series of Date in Openoffice

For example

If I am entering the date as 04/APR/2013 (2 months) this has to increase in each below column. The most important thing is if it is saturday or sunday i need it in different color or some differentiate.

Could any one help me on this

Thanks & Regards
Maha

Comment: http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_Functions_listed_by_category

Answer (score 0):

Assuming column A, put the date in A1, then put the following formula in A2;

```
=A1 + 1
```

Copy the formula as far down the column as you want.

I'm not sure how you want to indicate weekends.  You can use some combination of WEEKDAY and STYLE.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for choosing a date that is independent of locale (ie `dd` = `MM`).

I am assuming capitalisation of the whole of the month short name is not critical as arranging that would complicate meeting the rest of your requirements.

First (say in A1) enter:

```
4/4/13
```

then Format > Cells > Numbers `Date` and `31/Dec/1999`, and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.
Then click on the fill handle (the small black square at the bottom right-hand corner of the cell) of cell A1 and drag down to suit (for two months about 60 rows).

Next select your 60 or so cells, Format > Conditional Formatting… and for Condition1 select `Formula is` and enter:

```
WEEKDAY(A1;4)>4
```

then select your style of choice and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.